# Symfony 5 JSON Response / VueJS / Axios Error Handling - Custom Error Message

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, symfony, axios

I want to display a custom error message if my json Response throw an error.

In some of my services I throw an error like this:

```
if (count($recipients) === 0) {
    throw new TransportException($this->carrierService::ERROR_NO_MAIL_ADDRESSES);
}
```

In `carrierService::ERROR_NO_MAIL_ADDRESSES` there is my "Custom" Error Message:

```
const ERROR_NO_MAIL_ADDRESSES = 'No email addresses are available';
```

In my Controller I catch this Exception:

```
        $return = $serializer->serialize($assignment, JsonEncoder::FORMAT);
        $headers = [];

        try {
            $assignmentMailService->sendAssignmentMail($assignment);
        } catch (TransportExceptionInterface $exception) {
            $return = $serializer->serialize([], JsonEncoder::FORMAT);
            $status = Response::HTTP_BAD_GATEWAY;
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            $return = $serializer->serialize([], JsonEncoder::FORMAT);
            $status = Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
        }

        return new JsonResponse(
            $return,
            $status,
            $headers,
            true
        );
```

And in my *.vue this is my Axios Post Request:

```
        sendAssignment(id) {
            axios.get(this.route.generate('api_assignment_mail_send_assignment', { id: id} ))
                .then(response => {
                this.flashMessage.show({
                    status: 'success',
                    title: 'Info',
                    message: 'This assignment ' + response.data.ref + ' was sent!'
                })
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.flashMessage.show({
                    status: 'error',
                    title: 'Info',
                    message: 'This assignment cannot be send: ' + error.response.statusText
                })
            })
```

So I works right now ... if there is are no recipients the user get this message:

> This assignment cannot be send: Bad Gateway

But what I want is this message:

> This assignment cannot be send: No email addresses are available

But how can I send this custom message to Axios?
This error variable in that .catch function does not contain my custom message:

```
.catch(error => {
     this.error = error.response
})
```

I think it could be that I get the message from `error.data` of that `.catch(error => {....` function , but `error.data` is always `"undefined"`. How can I fill this `error.data` ?
Also if I try to fill my "`data`" array of my Json Response with `['error' => 'ErrorMessage']` this `error.data` is empty:

```
    return new JsonResponse(
        ['error' => 'ErrorMessage'],
        $status,
        $headers,
        true
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer by myself...

it is NOT `error.data` .. it is `error.response.data`

Like in my case:

Controller:

```
return new JsonResponse(
    ['error' => 'ErrorMessage'],
    $status,
    $headers,
    true
);
```

VueJS / JS

```
           .catch(error => {
                this.flashMessage.show({
                    status: 'error',
                    title: 'Info',
                    message: 'This assignment cannot be send: ' + error.response.data.error
                })
            })
```